# CGFloatのfor in文

Tags: swift3

「画像を指定のサイズになるまで圧縮する」という処理をするために、下のURLに載っているコードをSwift2.3で使っていたのですが、Cスタイルのfor文(No.1)をSwift3.0に書き直そうとしたところ、エラーが出ました(No.3)。

CGFloatの値でfor in文をつくるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

http://seeku.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/03/06/193628

No.1 画像を指定のサイズになるまで圧縮するfor文

```
for qualityUse = qualityMax; qualityUse >= qualityMin; qualityUse -= qualityDif {
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resize, qualityUse)
    if checkDataSize(data) {
    return data
    }
  }
```

No.2 swift3.0で書き直したコード

```
    for qualityUse in qualityMax...qualityMin as [CGFloat]{
        qualityUse -= qualityDif
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resize, qualityUse)
        if checkDataSize(data) {
            return data
        }
    }
```

No.3 No.2に対して出たエラー

```
    No '...' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '[CGFloat]'
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

やりたいことを実現できるのは下記のコードじゃないかと思いますが、いかがでしょうか？

```
for qualityUse in stride(from: qualityMax, to: qualityMin, by: -qualityDif) {
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resize, qualityUse)
    if checkDataSize(data) {
        return data
    }
}
```